# Angular 6 subscribe changes 'this' context

Tags: angular, service, angular6

I got my service working back on angular 5, now updating to angular 6 seems to need a bit of tweaking, every tutorial or video I find is labeled as angular 6 but is using angular 5 or a previous version, anyways, here is my code:

Service

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUsers() {
    return this.http
      .get(environment.server.url + 'users');
  };

  addUser(user: User) {
    return this.http
      .post(environment.server.url + 'users/', user);
  };
}
```

Component

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(res => {
     this.users = res;
   });
 };
```

When debugging I get the desired response from the server, an array of users but what fails is the **this.users = res**, this is bound to **SafeSubscriber**, not to the correct one with the users object.

Using fat-arrow I get the safesubscriber bound to 'this'
[image]

Comment: If you're using the fat arrow syntax (as you are in the example above), then it should bind the context of `this`. It's only an issue if you don't use fat arrow

Comment: Any chance you can reproduce this on stackblitz?

Comment: Uploaded a screenshoot inspecting the 'this', whill try to reproduce on stackblitz

Comment: I think you'll probably find at runtime, it's correct. This appears to be a case of the IDE getting it wrong

Comment: @user184994 you are right, been 2 hours stuck and it's a bug with visual studio code debugger, chrome console shows it right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug with visual studio code debugger, when using chrome console it is shown correctly.